# Creating JSON in android

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, bigdata

Please have a look at the following. They are JSON formats. Don't worry about the username and id. THhey are fake. You can see the link [here](https://bigml.com/developers/predictions#p_create)

**Authenticate**

```
POST /andromeda/prediction?username=alfred;api_key=79138a622755a2383660347f895444b1eb927730; HTTP/1.1
Host: bigml.io
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Creating Prediction**

```
curl https://bigml.io/andromeda/prediction?$BIGML_AUTH \
-X POST \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"model": "model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008", "input_data": {"000001": 3}}'
```

Above, `BIGML_AUTH` means a variable which includes the user name and the API key.

Now, I am going to do these JSON calls with android. Below is my code

```
private JSONObject putJson()
  {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      JSONObject finalResult = null;


      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://bigml.io/andromeda/prediction?username=alfred;api_key=79138a622755a2383660347f895444b1eb927730");
      httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

      try {
          // Add your data
          json.put("model","model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008");
          json.put("input_data", "{000001:3}");
          StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
          httppost.setEntity(se);

          // Execute HTTP Post Request
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(
                          response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
          String jsonString = reader.readLine();
          JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonString);

          finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          Log.d("Error here", "Error is here",e);
      }

      return finalResult;

  }
```

I need to know whether I have coded the given `Json` in Android correctly. I can't run and check because when run and checked, it returns *ID DOES NOT EXIST* error.

Please let me know whether I have coded the `JSON` correctly, because I have not use JSON before.

Comment: This code looks fine to me. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) is an article which talks about using JSON in Android

Comment: What json package are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference between your code and curl:

Your code:

```
      // Add your data
      json.put("model","model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008");
      json.put("input_data", "{000001:3}");
```

If you want to produce equivalent JSON as in your curl command, it should read:

```
      // Add your data
      json.put("model","model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008");
      JSONObject input_data = new JSONObject();
      input_data.put("000001", 3);
      json.put("input_data", input_data);
```

I encountered another thing which could cause problems. You read only the first line of your response. In many cases this is not a problem, because most JSON Objects are in single line. But if somebody enables DEBUG-mode on the API-server it can happen that the JSON object comes in multiple lines (aka. human readable).

BTW [Google doesn't encourage](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) developers to use `DefaultHttpClient` for Android versions > FROYO (makes ~ 97% of phones). For GINGERBREAD and newer we should use `HttpUrlConnection` for requesting web resources and REST/JSON.

I've made a small library called [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb) which makes live easier when making HTTP requests. With this library your code would look like this:

```
private JSONObject putJson() throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        // Add your data
        json.put("model", "model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008");
        JSONObject input_data = new JSONObject();
        input_data.put("000001", 3);
        json.put("input_data", input_data);

        Webb webb = Webb.create();
        result = webb
                .post("https://bigml.io/andromeda/prediction?username=alfred;api_key=79138a622755a2383660347f895444b1eb927730")
                .body(json)
                .ensureSuccess()
                .asJsonObject()
                .getBody();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // should not happen
        // Log.d("Error here", "Error is here",e);
    } catch (WebbException e) {
        // carries the real exception
    }
    return result;
}
```

The link I've provided gives many alternatives for HTTP-request libraries for Android - you don't have to use DavidWebb.

Comment: Thanks. Why am I getting 'FileNotFoundException' ? when I use your lib?

Comment: Probably there is a `404 Not Found` result. Can you pass me your stack-trace? You could create an issue on GitHub. For me it's not working - I get a java.net.HttpRetryException.

Comment: You can contact me if you search for my username or decrypt the contact in my profile.

Comment: I encountered that there is a [Java Binding for BigML](https://github.com/javinp/bigml-java). I'm afraid my lib is not the best choice here because new data has to be posted with `multipart/form-data` which is a feature I didn't want to implement in DavidWebb.

Answer (score 1):

org.json.JSONObject?

If so, then here your json code is fine & will give valid json too!

{
    "model": "model/50a2eac63c19200bd1000008",
    "input_data": "{000001:3}"
}